# Do i have to restart the server if i copy in some new files?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm copying in some new and modified files (aspx, css, dlls++) to a project of mine and I'm experiencing some issues.

Do I have to restart the web server thru the IIS manager GUI? When is restart necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make changes to css files sometimes your browser will store a cache of that file and you need to force refresh the browser or clear your cookies. I do believe when I worked on IIS I noticed that even if I cleared my cache my server still held a cache but in a little while it would refresh.  There may be a setting somewhere to not cache files (which I don't recommend for a production server) but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

IIS sometimes needs to be restarted after configuration changes within IIS.

I've made several changes to files IIS hosts and have never had to restart IIS for the website to function correctly.